# React native size, does it scale automatically depending on the size of device?

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm new to react native, and I have a question. Does react native scales the sizes of components depending on the device or what will be the best way to do it if it does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some libs to help with this, like: [react-native-responsive-fontsize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-fontsize)

Just config the width/height of your component with RFValue as:

```
import { RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize"

export function Welcome(){
return (
    <View style={{width: RFValue(50)}}>
       <Text style={styles.welcome}>Hello</Text>    
    </View>
)}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      welcome: {
        fontSize: RFValue(24) 
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: RFValue(10),
      },
});
```

You don't need to use this on every component or measure/size

Comment: Is react-native-responsive-fontsize only for for size or any size including width, height, etc.... Thank you in advance

Comment: you can use RFValue for everything, but as I said, this is just 1 way to solve this problem, there are others, and you don't need to use RFValue for everything, especially in small values, remember that you can also use values with %

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks a lot for your clarification and help!

Answer (score 0):

React Native by default doesn't scale component sizes. However, there are a few things you can implement while styling to make  sure it looks similar on all devices:

1. give widths and heights in percentages instead of numbers
2. use `flex` for views. this allocates a percentage of the screen to that component.
3. try to use `alignItems` and `justifyContent` as much as possible instead of giving values for aligning manually.
4. use `RFValue` from `react-native-responsive-fontsize`, which scales according to screen size.

This should make the app look similar on all devices

Comment: Is react-native-responsive-fontsize only for for size or any size including width, height, etc.... Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can use flexbox in react-native that will scale the components automatically to fill the space.

If you want to do more advanced style changes for different sizes will need more advanced solutions.  I really like the library restyle by shopify they have some solutions, but most likely flex will be all you need.

https://github.com/Shopify/restyle